# Matplotlib, how to plot from class attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, matplotlib, plot

I've created some classes, one of these classes is **class link:** that returns,

```
 return f" { ((self.component[0].xy) ,(self.component[1].xy)) }"
```

Then, by some loops, I can get several links:

```
 link1=((1, 1), (4, 5))
 link2=((2, 2), (6, 8))
 link3=((1, 1), (7, 10))
 link4=((2, 2), (5, 6))
 link5=((4, 4), (1,10))
 link6=((7, 7), (10, 6))
 link7=((4, 4), (2, 6))
 link8=((7, 7), (12,2))
```

I am trying to plot these links but i can't get the plot
it returns an error (float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'line'), for the way i am trying to follow:

```
ax = plt.subplot()
#ax.plot(link)
for m in range(0, 9)):
    ax.plot(all_links[m])
plt.show()
```

I tried to do something like link1[0][0],link1[0][1], but it gives an error ('line' object is not subscriptable)

Comment: Return tuples of numbers instead of strings.

Comment: if i remove f"", it gives __str__ returned non-string (type tuple), so i tried     def __str__(self):
        return  '{},{}'.format(self.component1[0].xy, self.component1[1].xy), but i still have the same errors as before

Comment: You do not show a [mcve] here, so I have no idea what you're talking about; but in any case, make sure to plot numbers, not strings

Comment: thank you, I changed it into numbers and it works now, and  I know I just wanted to show a simplified example of the problem I had.